# Middleware is not working (Laravel Livewire)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

Middleware is not working (Laravel Livewire)
I am trying to authenticate user using custom auth in laravel livewire but it is not working.
It opens all the route whether user is authenticated or not

**CustomAuth** (This is my middleware file)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CustomAuth
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $path = $request->path();
        if(($path=='login' ||$path=='register') && Session::get('user'))
        {
            return redirect()->route('/userpanel');
        }
        else if(($path!='login' && !Session::get('user')) && ($path!='register' && !Session::get('user')))
        {
            return redirect()->route('/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Kernal.php** (It is the Registration of middleware)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            //  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'customauth' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuth::class,
    ];
}
```

**web.php** (This is my Route file)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\home;
use App\Http\Livewire\Gallery;
use App\Http\Livewire\Video;
use App\Http\Livewire\Faq;
use App\Http\Livewire\Team;
use App\Http\Livewire\Price;
use App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Login;
use App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Register;
use App\Http\Livewire\Userpanel;




Route::group(['middleware'=>'customauth'],function () { 
    Route::get('/register',Register::class)->name('register');
    Route::get('/login',Login::class)->name('login');
    Route::get('/', Home::class)->name('home')->middleware('auth');    
    Route::get('/gallery',Gallery::class)->name('gallery');
    Route::get('/video',Video::class)->name('video');
    Route::get('/faq',Faq::class)->name('faq');
    Route::get('/team',Team::class)->name('team');
    Route::get('/price',Price::class)->name('price');
    Route::get('/userpanel',Userpanel::class)->name('user');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be an example of the use of middleware in the route page

`Route::get('/nuevopoais', Nuevopoais::class)->middleware('can:Nuevopoais_listar')->name('nuevopoais')`;

Answer (score 0):

Livewire has the config to set a middleware for its routes .
Check this please .

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/authorization

Answer (score 0):

**I got it. Middleware is not working because of route cache**
after running the following command it's work fine

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Thank you @Jesus Emanuel Becerra Santamar and @Mohamed Tahan for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is using **Laravel Spatie** and wants to protect their **Livewire methods**, they should do the following in their component:

1. Importar **AuthorizesRequests**

> ```
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
> ```

2. Use it inside the component

> ```
> class Actividades extends Component
> {
>    use AuthorizesRequests;
>    //More code...
> }
> ```

3. Call **authorize** in your method. Assuming you have a permission called "**activities.create**"

> ```
> public function store(){
>     $this->authorize('activities.create');
>     //More code...
> }
> ```